# Using RelativeTransform with a TileBrush

Tags: wpf

I am having exactly the problem described in the WPF documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970500.aspx

To quote:

> Because tile brushes are more complex than other brushes, applying a
>   RelativeTransform to one might produce unexpected results. For
>   example, take the following image.
>
> [image]
>
> The following example uses an ImageBrush to paint a rectangular area
>   with the preceding image. It applies a RotateTransform to the
>   ImageBrush object's RelativeTransform property, and sets its Stretch
>   property to UniformToFill, which should preserve the image's aspect
>   ratio when it is stretched to completely fill the rectangle.
>
> ```
> <Rectangle Width="200" Height="100" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
>   <Rectangle.Fill>
>     <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill">
>       <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
>         <BitmapImage UriSource="sampleImages\square.jpg" />
>       </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
>       <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
>         <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="90" />
>       </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
>     </ImageBrush>
>   </Rectangle.Fill>
> </Rectangle>
> ```
>
> This example produces the following output:
>
> [image]
>
> Notice that the image is distorted, even though the brush's Stretch
>   was set to UniformToFill. That's because the relative transform is
>   applied after the brush's Viewbox is mapped to its Viewport.

Does anyone know of a trick to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which was to use a [`TransformedBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.media.imaging.transformedbitmap%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to apply the rotation to the image at the beginning of the pipeline.